# Canjs - Extending can.Model with additional Methods

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I'm [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877422/canjs-add-custom-model-method) the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387020/more-restfunctions-on-canjs-model) person to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591609/canjs-model-service-method-implementations) this... the answers basically say "Well you're doing REST wrong." Fair enough, but development is filled with tradeoffs and I often find myself *not* in a position to rewrite the API.

Moving on to the problem at hand, what's the most elegant way to add a method for some resource to a model?

```
var Issue = can.Model.extend({
  findAll: 'GET Issues',
  findOne: 'GET Issues/{id}',
  findRelated: can.Model.makeFindAll(function(params) {
    return can.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'Issues/'+params.id+'/'
    });
  })
},{});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2196/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get an `Issue.List` from findRelated.

```
var Issue = can.Model.extend({
  findAll: 'GET Issues',
  findOne: 'GET Issues/{id}',

  findRelated: function(params) {
    var deferred = new can.Deferred();

    can.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'Issue/'+params.id+'/Related'
    }).then(function(response) {
      // success
      deferred.resolve(Issue.models(response || []));
    }, function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
      // failure
      deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred;
  }

},{});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2308/)

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar to the accepted answer, is to return `can.ajax` instead of creating a new deferred. It's a bit less verbose.

Also, as of v2.1, passing the response directly to `.models` is [deprecated](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.models.html) and converting it first with `.parseModels` is preferred.

```
    var Issue = can.Model.extend({
      findAll: 'GET Issues',
      findOne: 'GET Issues/{id}',

      findRelated: function(issue) {
        return can.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'Issue/'+issue.id+'/Related'
        }).then(function(response) {
          return this.models(this.parseModels(response));
        }.bind(this));
      }

    },{
      findRelated: function() {
        return this.constructor.findRelated(this);
      }
    });

    // usage examples
    // 1. Issue.findRelated({id: 1});
    // 2. new Issue({id: 1}).findRelated();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/2506/)